# How to replace text with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible I can replace my name with "anonymous" via jquery. but still keep my anchor tag with the specific link to a comment.
I couldn't figure it out so I tried removing the text and keeping the comment with

```
$('div.entryFooter').replaceWith($('div.entryFooter a'));
```

but it showed all the content from all three 'a' elements
in all of my divs.

Ideally, I just need the name replaced with "anonymous". My name will always be different so I need a way to find the name after "Posted by"

```
<div class="entryFooter">Posted by mjroodt at 24/10/2011 11:48<a href="/BlogPage.aspxid=20396&blogid=58906">Comments (1)</a></div>

<div class="entryFooter">Posted by mjroodt at 27/10/2011 13:33<a href="/BlogPage.aspx?id=12396&blogid=58945">Comments (2)</a></div>

<div class="entryFooter">Posted by mjroodt at 27/10/2011 15:59<a href="/BlogPage.aspx?id=14396&blogid=59963">Comments (7)</a></div>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that viewing the original HTML source will still simply reveal the original author?

Comment: @pimvdb, yes I am aware that the original author will be visible through the original HTML source but unfortunately I only have access to the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a few lines of Jquery below.  This solution will keep your anchor tags working as they were and you don't need to know the name you are trying to replace.

```
$('.entryFooter').each(function(){
    var html_arr = $(this).html().split(' ');
    html_arr[2] = 'anonymous';
    $(this).html(html_arr.join(' '));
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BzwwX/)

Answer (score 4):

No need for jQuery here. Just use the Javascript `replace([substring], [newstring])` function:

```
var value = $(".div.entryFooter").text().replace("James Johnson", "Anonymous");
```

Should be noted that this is only for the visual display. If you don't want the names to show at all, you'll need to parse them out at the server or database level.

```
$(".div.entryFooter").each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace("James Johnson", "Anonymous"));
});
```

Comment: Um..that *is* jQuery. Edit: well, really, jQuery is only used to retrieve the node from the DOM.

Comment: The `replace` function is not.

Comment: You can do it all in once shot as well. $(".div.entryFooter").text( $(".div.entryFooter").text().replace("James Johnson", "Anonymous") );

Comment: @Justin Carlson: That fetches the text of the first element and sets all elements' text to that, so it's probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: it the best solution, but only if you know the name

Comment: @mikhailov: It will still work fine. You can use the overload and pass a regex in place of the *substring* argument.

Answer (score 3):

This loop will **parse out the name**, whatever it might be, and replace it with in this case anon:

```
$('div').each(function () {
   var $this = $(this),
    text = $this.text(),
    name = text.match(/Posted by (.+) at .+/)[1]
   $this.text(text.replace(name, 'anon')) 
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Q2X/)

Using:

- [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)
- [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [jQuery.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide your real name, you have to adjust the server response.
For visual changes only, use the code below:

```
var name = "mjroodt";
var replaceBy = "anonymous";

//Generate a replace-all pattern
var pattern = new RegExp(name.replace(/([[^$.|?*+(){}])/g, '\\$1'), 'g');

//Loop through each `div.entryFooter` element
$("div.entryFooter").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    //Check if the name exists. Otherwise, ignore
    if(text.indexOf(name) == -1) return;
    $this.text(text.replace(pattern, replaceBy));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match any name and replace it with "anonymous" using the below code,

```
text.replace(/by[ ][a-zA-Z0-9]*[ ]at/,"by anonymous at");
```

The above would replace the content between "by" and "at" in the sentence "posted by xyz at" by "posted by anonymous at".

Comment: I think the character class for just one space is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to wrap text into span and iterate through them to change text() with RegExp:

see the work example for you requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/mikhailov/ypRsP/

**HTML**

```
<div class="entryFooter">
    <span>Posted by mjroodt at 24/10/2011 11:48</span>
    <a href="/BlogPage.aspxid=20396&blogid=58906">Comments (1)</a>
</div>

<div class="entryFooter">
    <span>Posted by mjroodt at 27/10/2011 13:33</span>
    <a href="/BlogPage.aspx?id=12396&blogid=58945">Comments (2)</a>
</div>

<div class="entryFooter">
    <span>Posted by mjroodt at 27/10/2011 15:59</span>
    <a href="/BlogPage.aspx?id=14396&blogid=59963">Comments (7)</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.entryFooter span').each(function(){
    var that    = $(this);
    var content = that.text();
    var t = content.replace(/^Posted by [A-Za-z]+/, "Posted by Anonymous");
    that.text(t);
});
```